# Does Spring Maven plugin use `dependency:tree` to populate `BOOT-INF/lib`?

Tags: spring, maven

For a simple project created through Spring Initializer, with only two dependencies:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

When I run `mvn dependency:tree -Dincludes=org.springframework:spring-core`, `spring-core` dependency is under `spring-boot-starter-test`:

```
org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:jar:3.1.5:test
\- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:6.0.13:compile
```

Even though Maven considers it to be dependency of test dependency, it's added to the bootable JAR. It seems that Spring Maven plugin uses different dependency tree than `mvn dependency:tree`, otherwise (I assume) it would have skipped `spring-core` from JAR as a test dependency.

Also, if I comment out `spring-boot-starter-test` from `pom.xml`, `mvn dependency:tree` moves `spring-core` under `spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server`:

```
org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server:jar:3.1.5:compile
\- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:3.1.5:compile
 \- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:6.0.13:compile
```

The main question:

1. Why and how Spring Maven plugin populates `BOOT-INF/lib`? Does it use Maven `dependency:tree` or its own rules/logic?

Derived questions (they seem to me related and easy to answer together with the main question, but I could ask them separately if that's more appropriate):

2. Is there any tool to view the Sping-way of viewing the dependency tree (i.e. the tree used to populate `BOOT-INF/lib`)?
3. Can we maybe force `dependency:tree` to prefer `compile` trees over `test` trees when there is such choice (as in example above)?

---

UPD: An answer for "Just try exactly this: `mvn dependency:tree -Dscope=compile -DoutputFile=result.log` and afterwards check the content of the file you will see it... Also the question is which version of maven-dependenc-plugin you are useing.."

The versions are:

- `maven-dependency-plugin` is `3.5.0`
- `spring-boot-maven-plugin` is `3.1.5`

`mvn dependency:tree -Dscope=compile -DoutputFile=result.log` produces:

```
com.example:bom-tree:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
\- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server:jar:3.1.5:compile
   +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:3.1.5:compile
   |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:jar:3.1.5:compile
   |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:jar:3.1.5:compile
   |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:jar:3.1.5:compile
   |  |  +- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.4.11:compile
   |  |  |  \- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.4.11:compile
   |  |  +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-to-slf4j:jar:2.20.0:compile
   |  |  |  \- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:jar:2.20.0:compile
   |  |  \- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:jar:2.0.9:compile
   |  +- jakarta.annotation:jakarta.annotation-api:jar:2.1.1:compile
   |  \- org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.33:compile
   +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-config:jar:6.1.5:compile
   |  +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:6.0.13:compile
   |  +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:6.0.13:compile
   |  \- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:6.0.13:compile
   +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:jar:6.1.5:compile
   |  +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-crypto:jar:6.1.5:compile
   |  +- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:6.0.13:compile
   |  \- io.micrometer:micrometer-observation:jar:1.11.5:compile
   |     \- io.micrometer:micrometer-commons:jar:1.11.5:compile
   +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-oauth2-resource-server:jar:6.1.5:compile
   |  +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-oauth2-core:jar:6.1.5:compile
   |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:6.0.13:compile
   |  \- org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:jar:6.1.5:compile
   \- org.springframework.security:spring-security-oauth2-jose:jar:6.1.5:compile
      \- com.nimbusds:nimbus-jose-jwt:jar:9.24.4:compile
         \- com.github.stephenc.jcip:jcip-annotations:jar:1.0-1:compile
```

No `spring-core` dependency.

Also, to show case my specific example, I've created small repo [here](https://github.com/vchernetskyi993/no-spring-core-in-compile).

Comment: `spring-core` is eventually used by almost all Spring dependencies, if you would manage to exclude it your application would stop working.

Comment: I don't want to exclude it. What I actually _want_ is for `dependency:tree` not to show it under `test` scope as, obviously, it's not only a `test` scope. But more importantly I want to understand why the discrepancy between `dependency:tree` and `spring-boot-maven-plugin`.

Comment: If you like to see only compile scoped dependency just use `mvn dependency:tree -Dscope=test`

Comment: @khmarbaise I assume you meant `mvn dependency:tree -Dscope=compile`, but that's exactly the problem. For the first tree `-Dscope=compile` shows no `spring-core` at all.

Comment: Just try exactly this: `mvn dependency:tree -Dscope=compile -DoutputFile=result.log` and afterwards check the content of the file you will see it... Also the question is which version of maven-dependenc-plugin you are useing..

Comment: @khmarbaise I've updated the question with more details. Please, take a look.

Comment: Ok... please show the full pom file or a link to your project....

Comment: BTW: The short answer to the question is: No the spring-boot-maven-plugin does not use maven-dependency-plugin:tree etc. Ah sorry there is already link...I will take a look..

Comment: @khmarbaise the link is in the end of the question: https://github.com/vchernetskyi993/no-spring-core-in-compile. Just created this sample using Spring Initializr.

Sorry as well about not seeing your "sorry" :)

Answer (score 0):

The result of `mvn dependency:tree -Dscope=compile -DoutputFile=result.log` looks like this:

```
com.soebes.spring.example:employee:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
+- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:3.1.5:compile
|  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:jar:3.1.5:compile
|  |  \- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:6.0.13:compile
|  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:jar:3.1.5:compile
|  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:jar:3.1.5:compile
|  |  +- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.4.11:compile
|  |  |  \- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.4.11:compile
|  |  +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-to-slf4j:jar:2.20.0:compile
|  |  |  \- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:jar:2.20.0:compile
|  |  \- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:jar:2.0.9:compile
|  +- jakarta.annotation:jakarta.annotation-api:jar:2.1.1:compile
|  +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:6.0.13:compile
|  |  \- org.springframework:spring-jcl:jar:6.0.13:compile
|  \- org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.33:compile
+- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:jar:3.1.5:compile
|  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop:jar:3.1.5:compile
|  |  +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:6.0.13:compile
|  |  \- org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:jar:1.9.20:compile
|  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc:jar:3.1.5:compile
|  |  +- com.zaxxer:HikariCP:jar:5.0.1:compile
|  |  \- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:6.0.13:compile
|  +- org.hibernate.orm:hibernate-core:jar:6.2.13.Final:compile
|  |  +- jakarta.persistence:jakarta.persistence-api:jar:3.1.0:compile
|  |  +- jakarta.transaction:jakarta.transaction-api:jar:2.0.1:compile
|  |  \- org.antlr:antlr4-runtime:jar:4.10.1:compile
|  +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa:jar:3.1.5:compile
|  |  +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons:jar:3.1.5:compile
|  |  +- org.springframework:spring-orm:jar:6.0.13:compile
|  |  +- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:6.0.13:compile
|  |  +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:6.0.13:compile
|  |  \- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:2.0.9:compile
|  \- org.springframework:spring-aspects:jar:6.0.13:compile
+- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-rest:jar:3.1.5:compile
|  \- org.springframework.data:spring-data-rest-webmvc:jar:4.1.5:compile
|     +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-rest-core:jar:4.1.5:compile
|     |  +- org.springframework.hateoas:spring-hateoas:jar:2.1.2:compile
|     |  +- org.springframework.plugin:spring-plugin-core:jar:3.0.0:compile
|     |  \- org.atteo:evo-inflector:jar:1.3:compile
|     +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.15.3:compile
|     |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.15.3:compile
|     \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.15.3:compile
+- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:jar:3.1.5:compile
|  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-json:jar:3.1.5:compile
|  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jdk8:jar:2.15.3:compile
|  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:jar:2.15.3:compile
|  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-parameter-names:jar:2.15.3:compile
|  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat:jar:3.1.5:compile
|  |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:jar:10.1.15:compile
|  |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-el:jar:10.1.15:compile
|  |  \- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-websocket:jar:10.1.15:compile
|  +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:6.0.13:compile
|  \- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:6.0.13:compile
|     \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:6.0.13:compile
+- org.springframework.modulith:spring-modulith-api:jar:1.1.0-RC1:compile
+- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator:jar:3.1.5:compile
|  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure:jar:3.1.5:compile
|  |  \- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-actuator:jar:3.1.5:compile
|  +- io.micrometer:micrometer-observation:jar:1.11.5:compile
|  |  \- io.micrometer:micrometer-commons:jar:1.11.5:compile
|  \- io.micrometer:micrometer-core:jar:1.11.5:compile
+- io.micrometer:micrometer-registry-prometheus:jar:1.11.5:compile
|  \- io.prometheus:simpleclient_common:jar:0.16.0:compile
|     \- io.prometheus:simpleclient:jar:0.16.0:compile
|        +- io.prometheus:simpleclient_tracer_otel:jar:0.16.0:compile
|        |  \- io.prometheus:simpleclient_tracer_common:jar:0.16.0:compile
|        \- io.prometheus:simpleclient_tracer_otel_agent:jar:0.16.0:compile
+- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools:jar:3.1.5:compile
\- org.springframework:spring-context-indexer:jar:6.0.13:compile
```

The output of the command looks like this:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] -----------------< com.soebes.spring.example:employee >-----------------
[INFO] Building Employee Demo Application 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO]   from pom.xml
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- dependency:3.6.1:tree (default-cli) @ employee ---
[INFO] Wrote dependency tree to: /Users/khm/ws-git-soebes/examples/spring-boot-plus-spring-data/result.log
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  0.703 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2023-11-08T16:40:06+01:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```